# Proof of continuity of the integral of a regulated function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is regulated, $F(x):= \int_c^x f$ for fixed $c \in (a,b)$, $F$ is differentiable at $c$ and $F'(c) = f(c)$. How would you prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$?

Comment: what do you mean by $f$ is 'regulated'?

Comment: As in $f$ is a regulated function, i.e. it can always be approximated, as close as you like, by a step function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function

Comment: You really should include that in your question, because it is not a very used notion. At least I didn't heard of it until now...

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $f$ is a uniform limit of step functions.

You can refer to *Undergraduate Analysis by Lang* for the proof of the generalized version of this result. There is an integral called the regulated integral and it is nicely developed in the book.